# Is GRANT DELETE TABLE t TO PUBLIC and the revoke the right to DELETE TABLE t FROM user1 possible?

Tags: oracle, permissions

I have a production database that has `GRANT`s TO `PUBLIC` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on specific tables of the production schema, table `t1` being one of these tables.

Say I want to create a user `user1` that cannot `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on table `t1`. Is there a way to revoke these privileges for `user1` while keeping the `GRANT`s `TO PUBLIC`?

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work?

Comment: You're right, I reformulated. Notice that I said "revoke" and not "`REVOKE`".

Comment: Granting critical rights to PUBLIC is a very bad idea. Very bad. At the very least, create a specific role, grant the rights to that role, and grant that role to the actual users that should be able to do those updates. Another option is to have application roles - a role that is dynamically enabled by the specific applications that need them.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind: Agreed, and that's what I'll do. But if the GRANTS to PUBLIC have been in production for decades, you have to take utmost care think, ask questions, rinse and repeat :) And actually learn smething in the process.

Comment: @mustaccio : Your question is fair, but the upvotes are undue. It is an "is it possible?" question. If I had an in-depth knowledge of the subject, I would be able to answer the question myself, and simply not come here ask the question. Whatever I have tried is on the grounds of my incomplete knowledge of the subject. I have actually tried to `REVOKE` the rights on the user, and it failed. But since I am not competent enough, this is not sufficient to conclude "No it's not possible".

Comment: Rights in Oracle are a complex animal. They can be granted directly to users. Or they can be granted to roles, granted to users. But they can also be granted to roles, themselves granted to other roles, themselves granted to other roles and eventually to users. Tracing what exact privileges a user has and how a user got them (via what suite of roles) can be challenging. Also it is very possible that a user got a right through multiple paths.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind : All you're saying there I witnessed. To me, it looks like rights in Oracle work as "Some user has a set of system/object privileges". Granting a privilege directly to the user asserts that the set contains this privilege. Granting a privilege to a role asserts the role (set of privileges) contains the privilege. Granting a role to a role asserts the former set is included in the latter set. And `REVOKE`ing just cancels an assertion (like the ones above), not a privilege. This is the intuition I formed while working on my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something is granted to PUBLIC, that's it.  There is no 'blacklist' or 'grant to public but not to Joe'.  You should manage this with profiles.

Comment: That's what I imagined. I find the Oracle documentation rather unclear on the "We're working on whitelist mode" point, although the technical explanations on the commands are OK.

Comment: Please cite your source for ""We're working on whitelist mode" point"

Comment: There is none, AFAICT, 'whitelist mode' is an oversimplification of mine. Your answer is the one talking about 'blacklist' or anything close to 'whitelist'. I figure there is more to Oracle security than what is said there. I think it's better not to elaborate any fuirther on the subject.